# How to deal with order migrate file?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

**I have model:**

```py
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    extend = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

At `migration` file with name: **005_remove_name**

I have a function:

```py
def remove_name(apps, schema_editor):
   Student = apps.get_model('myapp', 'Student')
   queryset = Student.objects.filter(name="Peter")
   if queryset:
        queryset.delete()
```

But during migrate operation, my screening show "missing column extend"

I figure out that **extend** column in **Student** table will have been added at migration file with name : **007_add_extend**.

```py
migrations.AddField(
            model_name='student',
            name='extend',
            field=models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True),
        ),
```

**My Error is :**

**How to queryset at migration file if column does not exist?**

Comment: How are you importing Student in your `0005` migration file? What's the context of that `queryset` code? Please [edit] your question and add a [mcve] of that migration file.

Comment: @Chris I haved updated migration file, I can't wait to see your solution

Comment: Hrm, that's not what I expected to see. It looks like you're using `apps.get_model()` correctly. Try running your migrations on a brand new database to see if they work starting from scratch.

Comment: @Chris I wonder, should I use raw SQL in this case. Anyway thank you for your solution

Comment: No, you probably shouldn't use raw SQL. Have you tried your migrations on a new database? Do they work there? I'm trying to determine if your migration files are inconsistent, or if your database is.